# How to prove that $\{x\in X: f_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable complex-valued functions on $X$. I need to prove that $\{x\in X:f_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$ is measurable.

My attempt is the following: for each $n\geq 1$, we can write $f_n$ as $f_n=u_n+iv_n$, where $u_n$ and $v_n$ are real-valued measurable functions on $X$. Furthermore, it is easy to show that
$\{x\in X:f_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}=\{x\in X:u_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}\cap \{x\in X:v_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$.
Then it suffices to show that $\{x\in X:u_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$ and $\{x\in X:v_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$ are both measurable.

In order to prove that $\{x\in X:u_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}$ is measurable, I have tried to express this set as the intersection or union of some countable collection of sets. But all my attempts failed. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{x\in X:f_n(x)\rightarrow 0\}=\bigcap_j \bigcup_i\bigcap_{n\geq i} \{x: |f_n(x)|<\frac 1 j\}$. Can you show that $\{x: |f_n(x)|<\frac 1 j\}$ is measurable?

Comment: I think $\cup_{n\geq i}$ should be $\cap_{n\geq i}$ instead, right?

Comment: @OSCAR Yes, corrected